# DataTable row() is always undefined and can't retrieve data from database

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, datatable, datatables

In my application, I have been trying to `display` all the data into `DataTable` from `database`.Instead I got the error from server,

> dataTable = s {context: Array(1), selector: {…}, tables: ƒ, table: ƒ,
> draw: ƒ, …}

The HTML table would be

```
<table id="user_data">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Apt ID</th>
        <th>Doctor </th>
        <th>Specialization</th>         
        <th>Patient </th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Apt Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Status but</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Here is the `Ajax query`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

fetch_data();
function fetch_data()
{
var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
        "retrieve": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax" : {
     url:"adminquery/fetch/fetch.php",
     method:"POST"
    }
    } );
}
});
```

The `fetch.php` is

```
<?php

session_start();

include ('../../auth/dbconnection.php');

$columns= array('apt_id','username','specilization','patient_name','type','apt_date','admin_status');

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM appointment as a,users as u  WHERE a.user_id= u.user_id ORDER BY a.apt_id DESC");

if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"])){

    $stmt .= '
    WHERE apt_id LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
    OR  username LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
    OR  specilization LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
    OR  patient_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
    OR  type LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"

    OR  apt_date LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
    OR  admin_status LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"

    ';
}
if (isset($_POST["order"])) {

    $stmt .= ' ORDER BY '.$columns[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].'    ';

}else{

    $stmt .= ' ORDER BY apt_id DESC';
}

$query1='';

if ($_POST["length"] != -1) {

    $stmt1 =  'LIMIT '.$_POST['start'] .' , '.$_POST['length'];
}

$number_filter_row= mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn,$stmt));
$result =mysqli_query($conn,$stmt.$stmt1);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$data=array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  
    $sub_array =array();
    $sub_array[] =   $row["apt_id"];
    $sub_array[] =$row["username"];
    $sub_array[] =$row["specilization"] ;
    $sub_array[] =$row["patient_name"] ;
    $sub_array[] =$row["type"] ;
    $sub_array[] = $row["apt_date"];

    if($row["admin_status"]=="0") {  
        $sub_array[] =' <span class="custom-badge status-red">Cancel</span>';
         } else if($row["admin_status"]=="1") {    
            $sub_array[] =' <span class="custom-badge status-green">Active</span>';
             } else {   
                $sub_array[] ='<span class="custom-badge status-blue">Pending</span>';

         } 

$sub_array[] =$row["type"] ;

$data[]=$sub_array;
}

function get($conn)
{

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM appointment as a,users as u  WHERE a.user_id= u.user_id ORDER BY a.apt_id DESC");
  $result =mysqli_query($conn,$stmt);
return mysqli_num_rows($result);

}           
$output= array(
    "draw"  => intval($_POST['draw']),
    "recordsTotal"  => get($conn),
    "recordsFiltered"  => $number_filter_row,
    "data"  => $data
    );

    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

I don't know where I went wrong. Someone can help me may highly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure your php(serverside) is returning data? I see you've prepared $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELE.. and later trying to concat query to this? $stmt .= ' ORDER B...

Comment: In console, it show like this

Comment: @shubham Any thing I went wrong

Comment: I'd suggest you check your php file properly, and see if its working properly. means, if its returning data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Appending query parts to $stmt, you have to append in $query,so

```
//$stmt .= ' ORDER BY apt_id DESC'; 
$query .= ' ORDER BY apt_id DESC';
```

Change these in all of your fetch.php,

Then check if your html and js code part is similar to https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

This should fix the problem.